# What is the formula for date range in spotfire?

Tags: spotfire, tibco, spotfire-analyst

I would like to filter my data in spotfire using a date range formula, like this Date > '2020-05-01'

May i know how to write this date rangr using spotfire formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be : `[ColumnName] > Date('2020-05-01)` This will take your string of '2020-05-01' and convert it to a date which can be used to compare to your date column. This can be used in data limiting expressions in a visual , calculated column or anywhere else an expression can be used.